# Hadoop ClassPath Single Node Cluster Mac OS

Tags: java, hadoop

Need Some help. Though there are lot of different answers available and also I tried them but couldn't make it work. I intsalled hadoop locally in my mac os and when I tried compiling the java programs I got the following errors. I know the problem is with the setting up the correct class path, but in may case providing the class path didn't make it work. I have installed hadoop under /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec

I have my java home set to export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
and class path set to export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

but still getting the below errors. Any suggestions for the setting up the correct class path would be appreciated.

LineIndexer.java:6: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
                           ^
LineIndexer.java:7: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
                           ^
LineIndexer.java:8: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:9: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:10: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:11: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:12: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:13: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:14: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:15: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:16: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:17: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
                               ^
LineIndexer.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MapReduceBase
location: class LineIndexer
  public static class LineIndexMapper extends MapReduceBase
                                              ^
LineIndexer.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Mapper
location: class LineIndexer
      implements Mapper {
                 ^
LineIndexer.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LongWritable
location: class LineIndexer
      implements Mapper {
                        ^
LineIndexer.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Text
location: class LineIndexer
      implements Mapper {
                                      ^

Comment: Can you post the method by which you're compiling the code (IDE, command line - if so please include the full command line?)

Comment: I'm using command line. this is the compilation method..                                            javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d lineindexer_classes LineIndexer.java

Comment: My HADOOP_HOME is set to /usr/local/cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your classpath is wrong, try this instead:

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/cellar/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
```

Or redefine your HADOOP_HOME env variable to be `/usr/local/cellar/hadoop-1.2.1`

Comment: thankyou. it helped. I used javac -classpath /usr/local/cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d lineindexer_classes LineIndexer.java  
and it got compiled.